# String::copy error

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code and get the error later described how do i correct this?
The objective behind is to parse the following sentence into variables :
temp1+temp2=10
Code:

```
int main()
{
    string line,var1;
    int limit,len;
    //some code here
    // parse function declarartion :string parse(string ,char ,int &)
    f1>>line;
    len=line.length();

    var1=parse(line,'+',limit);
    line.copy(line,len-limit,limit);
    //some code here
}
```

Error:

```
alice.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
alice.cpp:65:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::copy(std::string&, int, int&)’
alicebob.cpp:65:40: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:724:5: note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::copy(_CharT*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) const [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:724:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘char*’
```

Comment: `len` and `limit` need to be `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Maybe read [some docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy).

Comment: still the same, infACT size_t introduces more errors

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do? Using `std::string::copy` this way is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to copy a substring into another string, why don't you use `substr()` instead?

```
int main()
{
    std::string line("ceva5");
    std::string var1;
    int limit = 1,len;
    //some code here
    // parse function declarartion :string parse(string ,char ,int &)
//     f1>>line;
    len=line.length();
// 
//     var1=parse(line,'+',limit);
    line = line.substr(limit, len-limit);
    //some code here
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

This should do what you want.

---

**EDIT**: I have not implemented your function but changed the code to work as string's `copy()`.

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
is the error i am getting what next?

Answer (score -2):

Here is the explain: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/ ,The first arg is char*, So,Accroding to your question,I think your code should be

```
line.copy((char *)line.c_str(),len-limit,limit); // wrong code, lost the const
```

but this code is dangerous,Because std::copy()'s first arg is **an array of characters** to store the string 's substring, So,I think you code has something wrong.

Here is simple code:

```
std::string test1 = "test1";
char buffer[10] = {0};
test1.copy(buffer,2,3);
std::cout << "buffer is: " << buffer << std::endl;
```

and the output is :"buffer is: t1".

Comment: Avoid casting the result of c_str() to mutable and let a function change it, so even with a warning, you're answer is wrong too.  Showing an example with a temporary string would make the answer better.

Comment: Will the problem be solved if i use char * instead of string in the declaration of the variables itslef?

Comment: @stefaanv,Yes you are right ^_^, So I said this code is dangerous.My fault is had not said this point. think you. I just write code follow the question's point(in the question:"line.copy(line,len-limit,limit);)

Comment: @user256378,No, the problem is you code is wrong,you should have a good look at the api explain. you should new a buffer or a char[] as copy()'s first arg.

Comment: @user25678,If my answer has helped you ,could you select as the answer,thx.

Comment: @yetuweiba: even though the comments say "wrong code", you still say "I think the code should be", showing the wrong code.  Remove the code because afterwards you already show a working example.

Comment: @stefaanv, Thanks for your advice, I had edit my answer, First I show the wrong code, at last show the working code. So, I will not delete the wrong code